# Simultaneous Crescendo/Decrescendo: Technique, Typo, or Spicy Meme?

Tags: notation

[image]

What do you suppose this is? Is there a way this should be played, or is it just hilarious?

Comment: Presumably  you can infer that the whole piece should be being played backwards...?

Comment: That's just for beginners. Pros can play this as well: http://i.imgur.com/RdLCClr.jpg

Comment: Do you recall what piece this image came from?

Answer (score 2):

The `>` sign clearly applies to the two chords above it, meaning that the first one should be played stronger than the second. The slur above confirms that.

The *cresc.* applies to a longer stretch of music, telling you to slowly increase the *average* volume of the piece. It usually applies until the next absolute dynamic mark. There's a *p* near your excerpt, so the crescendo might run until an *f* somewhere in the next bars.

This is completely normal practice. Many pieces contain series if sigh motifs like this that increase in volume up to some climax.

Comment: This may be technically true, but it's an abysmal bit of typesetting.  If a long crescendo is desired but with a decrescendo in the middle, there should be multiple hairpins and/or  "cresc ... decresc.... cresc" written out.